# How many photos can a D5200 take with a fully charged battery?

Tags: battery, nikon-d5200

Can any Nikon D5200 user tell me how many shots I can get on a D5200 with a fully charged battery?

Answer (score 3):

A D5200 should be able to take about 500 shots per charge [according to Nikon](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d5200/features05.htm):

> The D5200's superior energy-saving design allows you to shoot approx.
>   500 shots per charge* with the EN-EL14 Rechargeable Li-ion Battery.
>
> *Based on CIPA Standards.

That number comes from an [industry standard](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-002_e.pdf) procedure for testing battery life of still cameras, and it's unlikely that your experience will exactly match the test conditions. Based on Romeo Ninov's comment below, we can modify Nikon's number and say that depending on how you use the camera, you should get 500 ±200 shots per charge.

Comment: Caleb, this is not very precise. It depend of shooter habits. Depend of usage of LCD display you can get from 300 to 700 shoots. And my personal experience with mode 3 of lens stabilization (canon) give me twice more shoots (compared to mode 1)

Comment: @RomeoNinov - Likely why the answer included "should" and "about". The info from Nikon is as good or better than an anecdote.

Comment: @RomeoNinov The number of variables involved makes it impossible to be precise about the number of shots per charge in day to day use. Things like the ambient temperature, whether you keep the back display on after each shot and for how long, use of built-in flash, autofocus, the type of lens, etc. all impact battery life. That's why [the CIPA standard](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-002_e.pdf) (PDF) carefully specifies the conditions and procedure. I can see how a range would be useful, though, so I'll add that based on your numbers.